# Error: The result of the expression "@[User::folder]+ @[User::sale]" on property "\Package.Connections[Excel Connection Manager]

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I am receiving the following exception once I tried to read the Excel path from a variable:

> [Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"] Error: The connection string format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager.

> Error: The result of the expression "@[User::folder]+ @[User::sale]" on property "\Package.Connections[Excel Connection Manager].Properties[ConnectionString]" cannot be written to the property. The expression was evaluated, but cannot be set on the property.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to assign the following expression to the `ConnectionString` property:

```
@[User::folder]+ @[User::sale]
```

Try to assign this expression to the `ExcelFilePath` property instead of the `ConnectionString`. Since the `ConnectionString` property has the following format:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

While you are looking to evaluate the Excel file path as an expression.